# how to pass string into a method as a keyword argument

Tags: python, function, datetime

Is it possible to pass a string as a keyword argument into a function/method?

the code below works just fine

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(end_time)
```

However, if I will pass a string into datetime.timedelta

```
delta = 'days=1'
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(delta)
print(end_time)
```

then it will return

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: str
```

But what if I get this "days=1" or "hours=2", or "seconds=5" from user input?

One way to make that work is to parse user input and create multiple if/elif statements.

Is there anything better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps pass in the named parameters using the `**` operator:

```
params=dict()
params['hours']=2
datetime.timedelta(**params)
# datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because a keyword argument is *syntax*, not data. The following is legal, though:

```
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(**dict([delta.split("=")]))
```

This

1. Splits `"days=1"` into `["days", "1"]`
2. Creates a dict `{"days": "1"}`
3. Uses the dict as a source of keyword arguments for `timedelta`